# How to associate a dataframe to a SHP polygon in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, shapefile

(Uploaded question) When I use `SHP files` in Google Earth and click on it, sometimes, I could see information that is displayed as a "pop-up". This is an example:

In this case, I have a dataframe in `Python` that contains relevant information that I would like to link to each respective polygon before to export it as a SHP with this code lines:

```
# Points
data = ['26-05-2022', '25-05-2024', 18, 'Acari', 'Ecorer', 40, -15.572136, -74.62736, 'Valid']
columns = ['Approval', 'Expiring', 'Zone', 'Project', 'Owner', 'Size(MW)', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Status']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Latitude'],df['Longitude'])]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='epsg:4326', geometry=geom)
```

Where `CT` is another dataframe that contains coordinates:

```
# Polygon
[['A', 539953.3394,  8278356.7631,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.572135812938946,  -74.62735981024672,  'Valid'],
['B',  543394.3582,  8278598.5842,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.569892965187252,  -74.59527065391799,  'Valid'],
['C',  544374.9396,  8275284.2101,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.599839630766777,  -74.58606516268479,  'Valid'],
['D',  545165.1468,  8272748.721,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.622747690023045,  -74.57864734907821,  'Valid'],
['E',  544788.7396,  8271839.3717,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.63097535601474,  -74.58214217679688,  'Valid'],
['F',  544531.8483,  8271218.7568,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.636590561754735,  -74.58452749145272,  'Valid'],
['G',  544456.7666,  8271027.6721,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18, 'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.638319383853226,  -74.58522449548815,  'Valid'],
['H',  542762.6508,  8271564.0591,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.6334994985371,  -74.60103947340889,  'Valid'],
['I',  539422.042,  8272621.7549,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18, 'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.623991822179361,  -74.63222276450333, 'Valid'],
['J',  539213.6429,  8272687.7377,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.62339855055848,  -74.63416799727298, 'Valid'],
['K',  539093.1442,  8272725.8897,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.623055506219488,  -74.63529274775954, 'Valid'],
['L',  538990.1647,  8272773.0558,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18, 'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.622630692945311,  -74.63625420113516, 'Valid'],
['M',  538932.8284,  8272868.6162,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18, 'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.621767660560035,  -74.63679061525991, 'Valid'],
['N',  538985.7452,  8273196.7002,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18, 'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.618800785309029,  -74.63630218613136, 'Valid'],
['O',  538687.323,  8273598.3445,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.61517429311052,  -74.63909247921848, 'Valid'],
['P',  538678.0626,  8274064.0121,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.610964542228787,  -74.63918622946272, 'Valid'],
['Q',  538924.4467,  8274264.8223,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.609145320024819,  -74.63689102823527, 'Valid'],
['R',  538947.8091,  8275898.3227,  '04-01-2022',  '04-01-2024',  18,  'Acari',  'ECORER',  40.0,  -15.594377201030477,  -74.63669908037944,'Valid']]

CTP = CT[['Latitude', 'Longitude']]
polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(CTP['Longitude'],CTP['Latitude']))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom])
polygonExport = polygon.sjoin(gdf, how='left')
polygon.to_file(filename=url + projectName + '.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

So, how could I associate `df` information to the `polygon` before I save it into SHP to have something similiar as this?

Comment: Could you please post an example of what that association would look like?

Comment: Can you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sounds like you want to [Create a GeoDataFrame from a DataFrame with coordinates](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay firstly, your code wasn't complete or reproducible at all.
But for your use case you can use [gpd.sjoin](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html)
This will connect the dataframe based on lat/long of the points with the polygon.

See example below:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import  Point

# Points
data = [['26-05-2022', '25-05-2024', 18, 'La Quebrada', 'Ecorer', 49.387774157332444, 83.45161530012626, 'In Effect']]
columns = ['Approval Date', 'Expiring Date', 'Zone', 'Project', 'Owner', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Status']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Latitude'],df['Longitude'])]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='epsg:4326', geometry=geom)

# Polygon 
CT = pd.DataFrame([['A', 491570.3984, 8340340.536],
['B', 489904.7803, 8346300.1778],
['C', 490269.4017, 8346486.0674],
['D', 490146.1051, 8347050.3125],
['E', 489647.7213, 8347249.0144],
['F', 488383.3197, 8351830.6802],
['H', 491729.1146, 8349476.4402],
['I', 498146.31, 8348131.19],
['J', 498293.5603, 8343802.8176],
['K', 496885.6292, 8343768.3656],
['L', 496916.4466, 8342839.3843],
['M', 498302.6741, 8342910.4866],
['N', 498398.2149, 8340421.8451]], columns=['index', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])
polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(CT['Longitude']/1e4,CT['Latitude']/1e5))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom])

polygon.sjoin(gdf, how='left')
```

Output:

| geometry | index_right | Approval Date | Expiring Date | Zone | Project | Owner | Latitude | Longitude | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| POLYGON ((49.15 83.40, ...)) | 0 | 26-05-2022 | 25-05-2024 | 18 | La Quebrada | Ecorer | 49.3878 | 83.4516 | In Effect |

Comment: I tried to figure out what is wrong with my code below. It gives me NAN values using "sjoin". I will update my question